# Creating instance of class template having private constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class template having a private constructor and a static member function to create an object of the class. How do I pass the class type to the function CreateInstance so that the constructor can be called with class type?

```
template <class T> class DelegateHandler: 
{
private:
   DelegateHandler(...);
public:
   static DelegateHandler* CreateInstance(...)
   { 
       DelegateHandler* pDeleGateHandler = new DelegateHandler<T>(...);
       return pDeleGateHandler;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the class type"? Pass what to where? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use

```
DelegateHandler* pDeleGateHandler = new DelegateHandler<T>(...);
```

in the `static` member function. It can be simply

```
DelegateHandler* pDeleGateHandler = new DelegateHandler(...);  // No <T>
```

and then you can use:

```
DelegateHandler<int>* var1 = DelegateHandler<int>::CreateInstance(...);
DelegateHandler<double>* var2 = DelegateHandler<double>::CreateInstance(...);
```

etc.

If you want to use

```
DelegateHandler<int>* var = DelegateHandler<double>::CreateInstance<int>(...);
```

there are ways of supporting that but it is not clear from your post whether you want to do that.